# ¿Cómo identificar unas coordenadas con un espacio de una matriz?

Tags: c++

El objetivo es hacer un sistema de coordenadas cartesianas para ver si dos rectángulos ─ azul y rojo ─ están en la región dada por otro rectángulo de dimensiones 12.5 y 8, y esa es la forma que se me ha ocurrido porque es la primera vez que programo. Ahora lo que quiero hacer es introducir las coordenadas de los vértices izquierdos inferiores y que de alguna manera se cree el rectángulo pequeño dentro de la región de 12.5 y 8, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
//Código:

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int main(){     
     const double Lx=12.5, Ly=8; //Declaración de las constantes Lx y Ly
     double Lx1, Ly1, Lx2, Ly2; //Declaración de las longitudes de los lados de los dos rectángulos

    
    //Creamos el sistema de coordenadas cartesiano
    int sistema[18][26];
    
    for (int i=17; i--;){
        sistema[18][0] = 0;
        sistema[i][0] = sistema[i+1][0]+0.5;
    }
    
    for (int k=0; k<26; k++){
        sistema[17][0] = 0;
        sistema[17][k] = sistema[17][k-1]+0.5;
    }
    
    for (int z=0; z<17; z++){
        for(int y=1; y<26; y++){
            sistema[z][y]=0;
        }
    }
      
    //Primer rectángulo
    std::cout<<"Introduzca el color del rectangulo: ";
    std::string a;
    std::cin>>a;
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca las coordenadas de su vértice inferior izquierdo: ";/*Aqui falta código porque primero necesito tener lo de la matriz que funcione*/
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca la longitud de la base: ";
    std::cin>>Lx1;
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca la longitud de la altura: ";
    std::cin>>Ly1;
    
    //Segundo rectángulo
    std::cout<<"Introduzca el color del rectangulo: ";
    std::string b;
    std::cin>>b;
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca las coordenadas de su vértice inferior izquierdo: ";
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca la longitud de la base: ";
    std::cin>>Lx2;
    
    std::cout<<"Introduzca la longitud de la altura: ";
    std::cin>>Ly2;
    
    //Comprobación de los colores
    if(a =="azul" && b=="rojo" | a=="azul" && b=="rojo" ){
        std::cout<<"Los colores estan bien introducidos"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"Los colores estan mal introducidos"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    //Comprobación de las longitudes
    if(0<Lx1<Lx && 0<Lx2<Lx){
        std::cout<<"Las longitudes de las bases están bien introducidas"<<std::endl;
    }
    if(0<Ly1<Ly && 0<Ly2<Ly){
        std::cout<<"Las longitudes de las alturas están bien introducidas"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas el tipo `double` para definir las coordenadas de los rectángulos, va a ser imposible que puedas plasmar el problema en una matriz de números enteros. El tipo `double` admite decimales, por lo que la matriz tendría que ser lo suficientemente grande como para admitir tantos decimales como precision necesites. Es decir, si necesitases una precisión de 3 decimales y los valores fuesen de 0 a 10, la matriz tendría que ser de 10000x10000, 10^(DIGITOS_ENTEROS+DECIMALES)

Así que necesitas un enfoque diferente.

Así, por ejemplo, podemos tener en cuenta que todo rectángulo viene definido por la intersección de 4 rectas:

- Dos verticales: x1, x2
- Dos horizontales: y1, y2

En esta parte es vital que se cumpla que `x1 < x2` y que `y1 < y2`.

El caso es que traducido a código tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    double x1, x2;
    double y1, y2;
};
```

Para calcular el solapamiento se tiene que cumplir que al menos una línea horizontal y una vertical correspondientes a uno de los dos rectángulos se encuentren entre medias de las líneas horizontales y verticales del otro rectángulo

```
Solapamientos

+---+        +------+
|   |        |      |
| +----+     | +--+ |
| |    |     | |  | |
+-|    |     | +--+ |
  +----+     +------+
```

O, dicho a la inversa, sabemos que no hay solapamiento cuando un rectángulo está totalmente a la derecha o debajo del otro:

```
A la derecha               Encima
+----+                     +------+ 
|    | +--------+          |      |
|    | |        |          +------+
+----+ +--------+
                             +--+
                             |  |
                             +--+
```

Estos chequeos, con código, podrían quedar así:

```
Rectangle r1;
Rectangle r2;

// Descartamos aquellos casos en los que un rectangulo
// este totalmente a la derecha o totalmente encima del otro
if (r1.x1 >= r1.x2 || r2.x1 >= r1.x2 || r1.y1 >= r1.y2 || r2.y1 >= r1.y2)
{
    // No hay solapamiento
}
else
{
    // hay solapamiento.
    // Si un rectángulo no está ni completamente encima, ni lado del otro,
    // entonces debe existir solapamiento
}
```

Habría que verificar los casos límite, cuando las aristas de los dos rectángulos están muy muy juntas, pero por lo demás entinendo que con esto deberías tener suficiente.

Este algoritmo no tiene en cuenta los casos en los que un rectángulo pueda estar rotado. Asume que ambos rectángulos están perfectamente alineados al eje XY